# How to change the app's background and foreground colours programatically when using contraint layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've been struggling to find a way to do this.

There are some answers on stackoverflow showing how to to this with other layout types, but I couldn't find or figure out by myself how can this be done when one is using the constraint layout?

Any suggestions?

What I am trying to do is to change my app's BG/FG colours if  a certain menu with the corresponding colour is picked.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int idBC = item.getItemId();
    int idFC = item.getItemId();

    int idred = item.getItemId();


    if (idred == R.id.red) {

      //IF TRUE CHANGE BACGROUND COLOUR

        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here is my  `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.martin.ex2.MainActivity">




</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the `menu_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/fc"
    android:title="Foreground Colour">

<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:title="Red" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:title="Blue" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/green"
        android:title="Green" />
</menu>



</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/bc"
    android:title="Background Colour">

<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/brown"
        android:title="Brown" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/purple"
        android:title="Purple" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/orange"
        android:title="Orange" />
</menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Can you add some parts of your code and the problem you're facing exactly ?

Comment: @gahfy I added some extra code. I though that my question can be also a more general one, that's why I didn't add any code initially. :)

Comment: Ok, and what do you mean by foreground color ? You mean the color of the textviews and so on that will be included in your constraint layout ?

Comment: yes, that's right. Buttons, textviews, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For changing background, you may call [`setBackground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) or [`setBackgroundColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int))

For changing the foreground color, you will have to change it view by view, there is no other way to do it

Comment: what should i call this methods on? Should I create an object? Can you demo?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view); 
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#24a2c9"));
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.